# Vercel PostgreSQL websockets error in Next.js

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, websocket, error-handling

I am using vercel postgreSQL in my next.js app, i also tried neon db, but on using the db in my api section it is giving error.
**My api code is here:**
`
import { db } from "@vercel/postgres"

```
export async function GET(request:Request) {
    await db.connect()
    return Response.json({name:"muaaz"})
}
```

`
**And in terminal it is giving error:**

```
F:./code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/client.js
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "F:./code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/client.js" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "f:" URIs.
Import trace for requested module:
F:./code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/client.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/.next/fallback-build-manifest.json'
    at Object.readFileUtf8 (/home/kazaloops/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.268/out/buildHook/index.js:1144:66639)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:453:20)
    at loadManifest (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-manifest.js:30:54)
    at loadManifestWithRetries (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:34:51)
    at async loadDefaultErrorComponentsImpl (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-default-error-components.js:30:24)
    at async DevServer.getFallbackErrorComponents (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:560:16)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2127:40)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:902:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:225:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:798:17) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/mnt/mydisk/F:/code/dbprac/intro/.next/fallback-build-manifest.json'
}
```

I tried using other postgreSQL db like neon, but the error is same

I tried using other db like Neon Db, but it did not worked